# Isn't the term RAM technically incorrect?

Tags: ram

I know that RAM is a word used to describe a type of memory that is volatile and more importantly doesn't have a speed difference when accessing different parts of the "memory grid". Isn't the last characteristic of RAM(no speed difference between accessing different areas of the memory)  technically not possible because it depends on the length of the wires going to that intersection of the grid from the two decoders?I know that some of my terms are incorrect and may be misleading so here is an example diagram of a RAM chip(on the first page there is an architectural diagram):

http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/Datasheets/6264.pdf

On the datasheet the "memory grid" is called the array, and two decoders are used with the address input so that one "intersection" can only be "active" at once.

Comment: where does the word RAM describe anything about the speed?

Comment: RAM stands for Random Access Memory which basically means that any random part of RAM can be "chosen" and accessed without any speed difference compared to accessing a different random part of RAM. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: (a) this is useless pedantry of the worst kind (b) at that length the wire behaves more like a lumped capacitance (c) the read delay in the chip is fixed at worst-case as there's no way of measuring when the signal has arrived

Comment: @zack1544: yes, you are wrong, it simply means you can access random parts of the memory without having to access other parts first, like in delay line memory or tapes or so

Comment: Wikipedia says "almost same amount of time irrespective of the physical location of data inside the memory".

Comment: @RespawnedFluff: and for NUMA systems, the "almost" is quite a stretch, and it really isn't part of the definition, just an attribute that todays systems have. It wasn't really part of it when the term was coined as a distinguishing feature. the article even introduces with delay lines.

Comment: RAM has nothing to do with volatility. FeRAM, PCRAM (PRAM), Battery Backed SRAM, etc. are all non-volatile.

Comment: And `DRAM` has a refresh cycle which can delay any access to a very long time *sometimes*.

Comment: @gbulmer it's the phrasing of the title; "isn't (commonly used and widely understood term) technically incorrect" I've seen too often used as a gotcha. If the answer were "yes", would he start going round correcting people who called DRAM RAM, to the confusion of everyone? The question body is entirely reasonable.

Comment: @pjc50 - Ah! So if it the title were something like "How can RAM have no speed difference when accessing different areas of the same memory chip?" It'd be okay? Now I understand you, I'll delete my comment.

Comment: Wait, do you mean my "fixed" or "hard" disk is _sometimes_ neither, as well?! Is everything I've ever heard a lie?

Comment: Does it really matter?

Comment: @gbulmer yes, a less leading question :)

Comment: RAM was a term stated using in early days of computing.  Its Random compared to sequentially accessed storage devices like Tape drives used in those days.

Comment: And how about Electrically Erasable Programmable 'Read Only' Memory(EEPROM) ? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Isn't the last characteristic of RAM(no speed difference between accessing different areas of the memory) technically not possible

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory) "almost same amount of time irrespective of the physical location of data inside the memory". And then

> Even within a hierarchy level such as DRAM, the specific row, column, bank, rank, channel, or interleave organization of the components make the access time variable, although not to the extent that rotating storage media or a tape is variable.

And to stick with DRAM [as example](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/%7Ehyesoon/fall11/lec_dram.pdf)

> DRAM bank latency
>
> - Simple CAS if row is “open” OR
> - RAS + CAS if array precharged OR
> - PRE + RAS + CAS (worst case)

The speed differences are going to be less significant in a SRAM, which lacks this more complicated access model that DRAM has.

Here's a latency (=speed) comparison in an actual (albeit fairly old) [system](https://books.google.com/books?id=0xRqj8IXCSIC&pg=PA18):

[image]

There's almost no discernible latency (=speed) variation for SRAM, but there's a lot more for DRAM. The sudden vertical you see is when the SRAM (bandwidth) saturates.

And you do have [intra-die latency variations](https://www.ece.cmu.edu/%7Etruss/papers/selse09-modeling.pdf) between cells even for SRAM; the following graph is for a [simulated] 45nm process. [SECDEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code#Hamming_codes_with_additional_parity_.28SECDED.29) ECC can be used to mask away the speed of the slowest cells; otherwise these would determine the (speed/latency) performance of the entire chip as the lowest common denominator.

[image]

And, yeah, even from a [purely geometric/layout perspective](https://books.google.com/books?id=DGvxLjGatOcC&pg=PA21), ignoring process variations, you'd have some speed difference between SRAM cells. That thesis says that in simulation [of 64Kb SRAM in 65nm process] the speed difference between the slowest (farthest) and fastest (closest) cell is between 5% and 15% based on layout alone.

[image]

Not that any of this is reason not to call it RAM anymore.

Answer (score 8):

The term RAM comes from the historic division between sequentially accessed memory (mercury delay lines, rotating drums and the like) and random accessible memory (like wilkinson tubes and ferrite core memory). All these memories were read-write (but in most cases a read was destructive or even time-boxed), so there was no urge to make a distinction between read-write and read-only. Of these types of memory only RAM survived, so we are stuck with that term for memory that can be read and written, and can be addressed (almost) at will, without (much) speed impact.

Some time later, memories began to appear that could be read, but not written (IIRC the bits were 'wired' by winding a wire clockwise or anti-clockwise around a peg). Those memories were randomly accessible, but to distinguish them from the read-write memory they were called Read-Only Memory or ROM.

Now we have all types of memory that are fussing the borders, like flash, which is a mostly-read but you-can-write-it-some-number-of-times memory.

So yes, the term RAM is at least partially misleading, but we are stuck with it.

(For you to research: why is a file that contains the image of a crashed program often called a 'core dump'?)

Answer (score 3):

"I know that RAM is a word used to describe a type of memory that is volatile and more importantly doesn't have a speed difference when accessing different parts of the "memory grid".

Well, no. RAM (random access memory) refers only to the ability of the system to modify the contents of the memory, as opposed to ROM (read-only memory) which cannot ordinarily be modified by the system. The distinction between the two has blurred considerably in recent years, both in terms of self-modification and volatility. Flash memory, for instance, for BIOS storage is ordinarily treated as a ROM, but it can be modified. Likewise, even 25 years ago Dallas Semiconductors was selling non-volatile RAMs, which had a backup battery as part of the package. So your ideas about RAM are clearly wrong.

If you could provide a source for your claim about speed differences, it would be helpful.

In modern systems, RAM timing is fixed, but this has not always been so. For example, in the old PC expansion scheme (ISA bus) any memory accessed by the system had the possibility of wait states being asserted by the accessed memory, and each physically distinct memory could assert a different number of wait states. The same was true of most minicomputer architectures. As a result, it was perfectly possible to mix memory cards, with wildly different access times available to the processor.

Comment: I have always interpreted the intended meaning of "RAM timing" to be within a single chip, or bank of chips with common timing and control, and not across an expansion bus. Expansion buses are usually intended to support a range of technology, beyond RAM. In that case, the last para feels a bit misleading if the OP is focused on RAM timing. Also the fact that different blocks of RAM have different timing is not necessarily in conflict with one interpretation of the OP's question, and may even be saying that their proposition (longer wires) is correct (which I don't think is).

Comment: @gbulmer - Nowadays RAM timing is generally used wrt a single chip or module, as you say. This is a consequence of current PC design, which uses a minimum number of physical components for RAM functions. It in no way applies to other, older technologies, many of which are still lurking around in legacy systems.

Comment: I still have (somewhere in the house) my old 80286 with 2MB expansion board. I worked on PDP11-34 with memory cards. I *had* an intimate working knowledge of them. However, my interpretation of the core of the OP's question "(no speed difference between accessing different areas of the memory) technically not possible because it depends on the length of the wires going to that intersection of the grid from the two decoders" *is only and exactly* talking about the internals of a single chip.

Comment: AMD used to make a static RAM which had an internal mechanism to provide a "data ready" output valid for each address. This would allow running any array of chips at maximum speed.

Comment: IIRC lots of manufacturers made chips that way with variations on read and write, like 'Data Valid', 'Data Latched'. So are you saying that the manufacturers asserted that signal more rapidly when the data within the chip travelled over shorter wires (and hence is relevant to the OPs question)? I don't think they did that. I think it was to support CPU to RAM protocols.

Comment: @gbulmer - No, as far as I know, AMD was the only manufacturer who tried it (and it never caught on), although if you provide counterexamples I'd be interested. Until fairly recently, wire length had little effect on RAM performance, and termination/undershoot/overshoot would have been the dominant effect rather than propagation time.

Comment: I haven't seen my old databooks for more than 25 years. I imagine they are somewhere, but the chances of finding them are low. I think it was very late 70's or early, maybe mid 80's. Based on what I used to look at, I'd guess they'd be Motorola, TI, or second sources like Signetics, or one of the 'mainly memory' manufacturers, *maybe* early INMOS, but I don't think so. I suppose, it might have been an AMD second source, or AMD were second sourcing someone else's chip, but I don't remember looking at AMD memory back then. I think it was before 1986.